# Не устанавливается PyAutoGui

Tags: python, pip, install

Вообщем,написал я в консоль pip install PyAutoGui,и мне выдало вот такую ошибку,люди помогите,что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _и мне выдало вот такую ошибку_, а какую ошибку? Дополните вопрос текстом сообщения об ошибке.

Comment: А ошибка то где?

Comment: Я смог прочитать, что ругается оно на файл sitecustomize.py - возможно, этот файл не в кодировке utf-8? ну и следующее, что приходит в голову - попробовать это на системе, где имя пользователя (и все пути к файлам в его профиле) не содержат русских букв. Хотя, возможно, это перебор. но виндовс же: выйти-войти...

Comment: `pip install wheel`